# I am looking for uClinux to download

Tags: uclinux

I am looking for uClinux version for st32f429 discovery
Where can i download uclinux free ?

Do you have any information how I can install uclinux to st32f429 discoveey board ? Thank you for developing.

Comment: Have you tried building your own uClinux distribution thanks to [this open source project](https://github.com/jserv/stm32f429-linux-builder)?

Comment: Thank you for your rely. I think that it is bootloader files. Because their found size is 30 kb. but i  diffrenet uclinux it size is 290 mb. So link that you shared is just bootloader ? should i install this files to st3f429 ?another link is https://github.com/AdrianHuang/uclinux/tree/MovingTux  Actually I am confused. Pls give me more details.